# Flask. Масштаб веб приложения на мобильной версии

Tags: python, flask

Как адекватно сверстать сайт на Flask что бы на мобильной версии отображалось не так будто он пытается декстопную версию запускать P.S в вебе инвалид не судите строго.

Comment: Во-первых, добавить [meta-тег viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport) c нужными вам настройками. Во-вторых, Flask не имеет никакого отношения к вёрстке

Answer (score 0):

Если работать именно на flask, то у Вас 3 варианта: рендерить 2 отдельные версии сайта ; рендерить на сервере и подключить css фреймворк с минимальным яваскриптом - bootstrap; писать сайт на яваскрипте angular, vue, react с большим выбором интерфейсов.

Скорее всего лучше начать с bootstrap